# wherebetween laravel not working with variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8, and I would like to get rows between two prices in my database.

I using this code to get my product:

```
$prd = Product::where($args)->whereBetween('price', [$request->min_price, $request->max_price])->get();
```

But the problem is when I use the code above and I `return $prd;` nothing returned but when I put a static number as `$request->min_price` or `$request->max_price` it works correctly

I must set one of them as a static number like this:

```
$prd = Product::where($args)->whereBetween('price', [100, $request->max_price])->get();
```

or:

```
$prd = Product::where($args)->whereBetween('price', [$request->min_price, 1000])->get();
```

Where is my problem or mistake?

Comment: check what your inputs actually are

Comment: I checked both of them, they come integer

Comment: have you tried to typecast them with integer, maybe they are numeric, `$prd = Product::where($args)->whereBetween('price', [(int)($request->min_price), (int)($request->max_price)])->get();`

Comment: this solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to typecast them with integer, maybe they are numeric,

```
$prd = Product::where($args)->whereBetween('price', [(int)($request->min_price), (int)($request->max_price)])->get();
```